# university task - return the adresses of all authors who wrote books for the publisher who published the book with the title "xy"

Tags: sql

i got the tables:

**author** - name x telephone number x adress

**book** - ISBN x title x NameOfAuthor

**publishedBy** - ISBN x PublisherNumber

**publisher** - PublisherNumber x Name x Adress

and the task is to return the adresses of all authors who wrote books for the publisher who published the book with the title "xy". I may not use Join operators.

I think you need to join the book with the title "xy" with published by using ISBN then join with published by using the publisherNumber then join with Book using the ISBN and then join with author using NameOfAuthor=Author.Name and then print out the adress from there... however i cant seem to put this into a proper SQL statement.

My try looked something like:

```
SELECT a.adress
FROM author a,
     book b,
     publishedBy p,
     book b2,
     publishedBy p2
WHERE b.title="xy" AND b.ISBN=h.ISBN AND h.publisherNumber=h2.publisherNumber
  AND h2.ISBN=b2.ISBN AND b2.NameOfAuthor=a.Name
```

However I am absolutely not sure if this could work or would be correct and would appreciate some feedback or a correct solution. Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: i would use join at any chance i can get but for university we may not use it for writing sql statements. thanks for tidying up the code, looks way easier to read now.

Comment: May not use explicit JOIN?!? It's 2021 now...

Comment: I do know that... i used joins at work and at job school as well... but the professor gives the grades so his words are the law.